# Is there a window control for Twitterbootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is there a window control for twitter bootstrap? just a draggable closable non modal window? in the window, I will be putting controls like color picker, input fields, sliders ... etc

It will be as an object inspector .. any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well bootstrap has slider (carousel), inputfields (not clear about this one)

Bootstrap is just a responsive framework. If you need controls like color picker etc, you may use JQuery UI along with bootstrap. It has amazing controls. All of your listed controls are present in JQuery UI

http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: thanks, I found this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/, I think its just what I want .. : )

Answer (score 0):

feature that u describe doenst available in twitter-bootstrap.
But, there is a cool ui framework for this, try Extjs (sencha.com).

Comment: Extjs price starts from $595.00! my website uses twitter-bootstrap already, it would be great if there is such a widget in twitter-bootstrap, this will make me avoid using extra libraries, extra download size ..